# Select number of records until the sum is less than 'n' - Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am working on Microsoft Access. My requirement is, User will give any percentage value and I have to find the number of IDs which form the percentage of the '`Value`' column. For e.g. in the below DataSet (it is sorted by descending of value column which is also required), the sum of all values is '8409131'.

```
ID          NAME  VALUE
1000000090  A     2295175
1000000974  B     1942753
1000015555  C     1887965
1000004864  D     1310400
1000015557  E     972838
```

If I enter 75%, the value is 65170765.25, so I need to return all the IDs which forms the '65170765', less than or equals to. So in this case below are the sum of values which are less than 65170765.

```
ID          NAME  VALUE
1000000090  A     2295175
1000000974  B     1942753
1000015555  C     1887965
```

Is this possible to achieve my requirement in Access SQL?

My plan is to make a running total column to find sum of first two rows and then sum of that value with next row. But in Access, I am not able to figure out  how to create incremental rows in select query also to achieve this.

Query I tried:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.NAME, T1.VALUE,(T1.VALUE + T2.VALUE)  
FROM (
    SELECT  ID , RUN_MANAGER.NAME AS NAME, RUN_MANAGER.REPORTING_PERIOD, SUM(VALUE) As VALUE 
    FROM DATA 
    INNER JOIN RUN_MANAGER 
    ON DATA.RUN_NUMBER=RUN_MANAGER.RUN_NUMBER 
    WHERE  RUN_MANAGER.NAME='A' 
    GROUP BY ID,RUN_MANAGER.NAME 
    ORDER BY SUM(VALUE) DESC) AS T1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID , RUN_MANAGER.NAME AS NAME, RUN_MANAGER.REPORTING_PERIOD, SUM(VALUE) As VALUE 
    FROM DATA 
    INNER JOIN RUN_MANAGER 
    ON DATA.RUN_NUMBER=RUN_MANAGER.RUN_NUMBER 
    WHERE  RUN_MANAGER.NAME='A' 
    GROUP BY ID,RUN_MANAGER.NAME 
    ORDER BY SUM(VALUE) DESC) AS T2
ON T1.ID=T2.ID+1
```

This is not a duplicate question. The problem is, this question is based on Access SQL and also I do not have any incremental ascending rows.

Comment: If you do not have any incremental ascending rows, how will you determine the sequence of rows? Or do you request a random selection?

Comment: @Gustav I have to add sequence rows, but in access i am not able to figure out adding sequential rows in select query.

Comment: But you can't add a sequence number in a query without some sorting. If no sorting can be defined, you can just as well use a random sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table like `t`:

```
ID          NAME VALUE
1000000090  A    2295175
1000000974  B    1942753
1000015555  C    1887965
1000004864  D    1310400
1000015557  E    972838
```

You can use this query:

```
SELECT  *   
FROM    t
WHERE   
    (SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM t ti WHERE ti.Name <= t.Name) < (SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM t ti) * 0.75
```

For this:

```
ID          NAME    VALUE
1000000090  A       2295175
1000000974  B       1942753
1000004864  D       1310400
```